# highchart - average value of serie for shown period

Tags: average, highcharts

Using Highstock, I've a serie timestamp / value

with different rangeselectors (hour, day, week, month,...) or zoomX

I want to display the average value for the displayed time period.

Now, I can compute the average of the overall series data:

```
for (i = 0; i < chart.series[0].yData.length; i++) {
 total += chart.series[0].yData[i];
} 
seriesAvg = (total / chart.series[0].yData.length).toFixed(4); // fix decimal to 4    places
$('#report1').html('<b>Average:</b>: '+ seriesAvg);
```

How to compute the average only on the displayed datapoints ? And to refresh automatically after zoom ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `series.processedYData` or `series.points`.

Comment: I can't find more info on preprocessedYData method ?

Comment: Sorry it should be processedYData, sorry. This is not part of the API, but this array contains all y-values.

Comment: does processedYData contain only **displayed** points or all series points ? I tried the following: var seriesMin=Math.min.apply(null, objHighStockchart.series[0].processedyData); but this does not work (undefined) ?

Comment: `Math.min` takes arguments one by one to compare, not array of values like processedYData.. Yes, there should be only displayed data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. I can't make a loop accross series to compute min/max/average of y-data displayed on the chart (after zooming, date selection,...). I've always undefined.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle with my current code. This code works and computes min/max/average for OVERALL data, not only displayed data. If I use processedyData instead, this does not work. Thank you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tparvais/pQM3e/)

Comment: Thank you the min & max are not updated based on the displayed values ? If I zoom, or change the date range, min/max are not refreshed ?

Comment: Have you even tried to fix that on your own..? There was just an example how to do it for average.. Fixed full example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pQM3e/4/

Answer (score -1):

I implemented the same but I notice that processedYdata is loading also one data more than the one showed at the screen.

for that reason i added one additional command to remove the first processedYData:

```
processedYData.splice(0, 1);
```

below is the final result of the function

```
function showStat(objHighStockchart) {

    for (j = 0; j < (json_data.length); j++) {
        var seriesAvg = 0, 
            processedYData = objHighStockchart.series[j].processedYData;
            processedYData.splice(0, 1);
        var seriesMin = Math.min.apply(null, processedYData);
        var seriesMax = Math.max.apply(null, processedYData);
        var i = 0
        var total = 0;
        console.log(processedYData);
        for (i = 1; i < processedYData.length; i++) {
            total += processedYData[i];
        }
        seriesAvg = (total / processedYData.length).toFixed(2); // fix decimal to 4 places

        $('#container_stat' + j).html(
            '<br>Statistics for ' + objHighStockchart.series[j].name + '<br>' +
            'Total: ' + total + ' logs<br>' +
            'Min: ' + seriesMin + ' logs<br>' +
            'Avg: ' + seriesAvg + ' logs<br>' +
            'Max: ' + seriesMax + ' logs<br>'
            + '---' + processedYData
            );
    }
};
```

Comment: @Randika this is an answer, not a question.  maerco if you are expanding the answer of another user you need to do it as a comment on that answer, not as it's own answer.  Once you get a little more rep you will be able to do that.